# Get a list of URLs from a site

Tags: web-crawler

I'm deploying a replacement site for a client but they don't want all their old pages to end in 404s. Keeping the old URL structure wasn't possible because it was hideous.

So I'm writing a 404 handler that should look for an old page being requested and do a permanent redirect to the new page. Problem is, I need a list of all the old page URLs.

I could do this manually, but I'd be interested if there are any apps that would provide me a list of relative (eg: /page/path, not http:/.../page/path) URLs just given the home page. Like a spider but one that doesn't care about the content other than to find deeper pages.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/329736/wget-recursively-retrieve-urls-from-specific-website

Answer (score 95, accepted):

I didn't mean to answer my own question but I just thought about running a sitemap generator. First one I found http://www.xml-sitemaps.com has a nice text output. Perfect for my needs.

Comment: But there is a limit of 5000 links!..:( I'm looking for any free php sitemap generator script.

Comment: Current limit is **500** — getting smaller…

Comment: It errored out for me: ::::::: An error occured

There was an error while accessing the URL specified: http://159.121.ssss/
Please make sure to specify the correct website URL and resubmit your request.

Comment: FYI: If you are using frontend routing you will not get those routes from this method.

Comment: FYI: if the website uses authentication and/or authorization you will not get all the routes either.

Comment: it doesnt work for dynamic url , example my own react website

Answer (score 61):

do `wget -r -l0 www.oldsite.com`

Then just `find www.oldsite.com` would reveal all urls, I believe.

Alternatively, just serve that custom not-found page on every 404 request!
I.e. if someone used the wrong link, he would get the page telling that page wasn't found, and making some hints about site's content.

Comment: Notably, since this returns a list of *files*, not URLs, this would only really work for sites that are collections of static HTML files.  If the site has URL query parameters, server-side rewritten URLs, or any kind of `include`/`require`/etc. assembling of pages, this won't really work.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding wget. I thought 'wget' was for downloading the contents of the site?

Comment: @Doomsy yes, but when you've downloaded all the content you surely know all the URLs to that content, and without downloading there's no way to find out URLs.

Comment: Consider the default depth. https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Recursive-Retrieval-Options.html#Recursive-Retrieval-Options

Comment: @PJBrunet thx, fixed!

Comment: @alamar Yes there's "-r -l inf" for infinite recursion, but I recommend people check out the documentation--so many cool options! The "-m" option will mirror and I'm going to try "-R.jpg,.jpeg,.gif,.png" which I think skips images.

Comment: can we export this list into a pdf file or excel file?

Comment: I don't see why not? `find -type f > urls.csv`

Answer (score 24):

Here is a list of sitemap generators (from which obviously you can get the list of URLs from a site): http://code.google.com/p/sitemap-generators/wiki/SitemapGenerators

> Web Sitemap Generators
>
> The following are links to tools that generate or maintain files in
>   the XML Sitemaps format, an open standard defined on sitemaps.org and
>   supported by the search engines such as Ask, Google, Microsoft Live
>   Search and Yahoo!. Sitemap files generally contain a collection of
>   URLs on a website along with some meta-data for these URLs. The
>   following tools generally generate "web-type" XML Sitemap and URL-list
>   files (some may also support other formats).
>
> Please Note: Google has not tested or verified the features or
>   security of the third party software listed on this site. Please
>   direct any questions regarding the software to the software's author.
>   We hope you enjoy these tools!
>
> Server-side Programs
>
> - Enarion phpSitemapsNG (PHP)
> - Google Sitemap Generator (Linux/Windows, 32/64bit, open-source)
> - Outil en PHP (French, PHP)
> - Perl Sitemap Generator (Perl)
> - Python Sitemap Generator (Python)
> - Simple Sitemaps (PHP)
> - SiteMap XML Dynamic Sitemap Generator (PHP) $
> - Sitemap generator for OS/2 (REXX-script)
> - XML Sitemap Generator (PHP) $
>
> CMS and Other Plugins:
>
> - ASP.NET - Sitemaps.Net
> - DotClear (Spanish)
> - DotClear (2)
> - Drupal
> - ECommerce Templates (PHP) $
> - Ecommerce Templates (PHP or ASP) $
> - LifeType
> - MediaWiki Sitemap generator
> - mnoGoSearch
> - OS Commerce
> - phpWebSite
> - Plone
> - RapidWeaver
> - Textpattern
> - vBulletin
> - Wikka Wiki (PHP)
> - WordPress
>
> Downloadable Tools
>
> - GSiteCrawler (Windows)
> - GWebCrawler & Sitemap Creator (Windows)
> - G-Mapper (Windows)
> - Inspyder Sitemap Creator (Windows) $
> - IntelliMapper (Windows) $
> - Microsys A1 Sitemap Generator (Windows) $
> - Rage Google Sitemap Automator $ (OS-X)
> - Screaming Frog SEO Spider and Sitemap generator (Windows/Mac) $
> - Site Map Pro (Windows) $
> - Sitemap Writer (Windows) $
> - Sitemap Generator by DevIntelligence (Windows)
> - Sorrowmans Sitemap Tools (Windows)
> - TheSiteMapper (Windows) $
> - Vigos Gsitemap (Windows)
> - Visual SEO Studio (Windows)
> - WebDesignPros Sitemap Generator (Java Webstart Application)
> - Weblight (Windows/Mac) $
> - WonderWebWare Sitemap Generator (Windows)
>
> Online Generators/Services
>
> - AuditMyPc.com Sitemap Generator
> - AutoMapIt
> - Autositemap $
> - Enarion phpSitemapsNG
> - Free Sitemap Generator
> - Neuroticweb.com Sitemap Generator
> - ROR Sitemap Generator
> - ScriptSocket Sitemap Generator
> - SeoUtility Sitemap Generator (Italian)
> - SitemapDoc
> - Sitemapspal
> - SitemapSubmit
> - Smart-IT-Consulting Google Sitemaps XML Validator
> - XML Sitemap Generator
> - XML-Sitemaps Generator
>
> CMS with integrated Sitemap generators
>
> - Concrete5
>
> Google News Sitemap Generators   The following plugins allow
>   publishers to update Google News Sitemap files, a variant of the
>   sitemaps.org protocol that we describe in our Help Center. In addition
>   to the normal properties of Sitemap files, Google News Sitemaps allow
>   publishers to describe the types of content they publish, along with
>   specifying levels of access for individual articles. More information
>   about Google News can be found in our Help Center and Help Forums.
>
> - WordPress Google News plugin
>
> Code Snippets / Libraries
>
> - ASP script
> - Emacs Lisp script
> - Java library
> - Perl script
> - PHP class
> - PHP generator script
>
> If you believe that a tool should be added or removed for a legitimate
>   reason, please leave a comment in the Webmaster Help Forum.

Comment: Is there anyone that provide a printscreen from all the url?

Comment: This is not helpful...

Answer (score 6):

The best on I have found is http://www.auditmypc.com/xml-sitemap.asp which uses Java, and has no limit on pages, and even lets you export results as a raw URL list.

It also uses sessions, so if you are using a CMS, make sure you are logged out before you run the crawl.

Comment: sounded good, but it's broken.

Answer (score 3):

So, in an ideal world you'd have a spec for all pages in your site. You would also have a test infrastructure that could hit all your pages to test them.

You're presumably not in an ideal world. Why not do this...?

1. Create a mapping between the well
   known old URLs and the new ones.
   Redirect when you see an old URL.
   I'd possibly consider presenting a
   "this page has moved, it's new url
   is XXX, you'll be redirected
   shortly".
2. If you have no mapping, present a
       "sorry - this page has moved. Here's
       a link to the home page" message and
       redirect them if you like.
3. Log all redirects - especially the
       ones with no mapping. Over time, add
       mappings for pages that are
       important.

Answer (score 2):

wget from a linux box might also be a good option as there are switches to spider and change it's output.

EDIT: wget is also available on Windows: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm

Answer (score 1):

Write a spider which reads in every html from disk and outputs every "href" attribute of an "a" element (can be done with a parser). Keep in mind which links belong to a certain page (this is common task for a MultiMap datastructre). After this you can produce a mapping file which acts as the input for the 404 handler.

Answer (score 1):

I would look into any number of online sitemap generation tools.  Personally, I've used [this one](http://www.auditmypc.com/xml-sitemap.asp) (java based)in the past, but if you do a google search for "sitemap builder" I'm sure you'll find lots of different options.