# Search in html source with GOOGLE?

Tags: search, web-crawler, search-engine, keyword

I have several websites, and I can't remember where I wrote some lines of code. As my pages are indexed by Google, I would like to know if Google offers a facility to search within the HTML source code/mark-up itself, *instead of* just allowing search within the visual, rendered, part of a page?

Thanks

Comment: Is the code on the client side or the server?

Comment: very easy with http://nerdydata.com

Comment: Sometimes I don't really understand the moderators here. Closing this well voted question after 11 years?

Answer (score 45):

I've come across the following resources on my travels (some already mentioned above):

**HTML Mark-up-focused search engines**

- [Nerdydata](https://www.nerdydata.com/)

I'd also like to throw in the following:

**Huge, website crawl data archives**

- [Common Crawl - 'years of free web page data to help change the world' (over 250TB+)](https://commoncrawl.org/)

**How can we analyze this crawl data?**

For an idea of how to begin analyzing some of this massive data, take a look at [Big Data/Map-reduce-type frameworks(s)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce).

[Google lists some ideas on using Apache's Spark project](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22common+crawl%22+apache+spark) to analyze [Common Crawl's dump(s)](https://commoncrawl.org/). To understand [the file format(s) used by Common Crawl](https://commoncrawl.org/the-data/get-started/), refer to the following:

- [So you’re ready to get started [with Common Crawl]](https://commoncrawl.org/the-data/get-started/)
- [Navigating the WARC file format [by Common Crawl]](https://commoncrawl.org/2014/04/navigating-the-warc-file-format/)

The article, [Accessing-Common-Crawl-Dataset-on-S3](https://web.archive.org/web/20150717212807/https://hackinghabits.com/2014/03/29/Accessing-Common-Crawl-Dataset-on-S3), outlines accessing [Common Crawl's 250TB+ dump(s)](https://commoncrawl.org/) in a low cost manner ***without*** transferring that data load outside of Amazon's AWS/S3 network. Of course, that assumes you *are* going to use some combination [AWS/EC2/S3](http://aws.amazon.com) etc. to analyze the crawl data.

Finally, [Patrick Durusau](http://tm.durusau.net/) maintains [some interesting Common-Crawl-usage-related blog pages](http://tm.durusau.net/?cat=882).

Personally, I find this subject intriguing, I suggest we **get this crawl data while it's HOT!** ;-)

Comment: In my case, the site engine is leaking private urls from a particular domain *(I am sure it doesn’t come from users)*. How I can the search in the source of a single domain ? *(in order to find where the leak come from )*

Comment: Assuming you have access to a Unix-like Bash console (try 'Git Bash', unxutils or cygwin on Windows), you could use a number of solutions based on various combinations of wget/curl/xidel/grep/awk for example. [This SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804467/spider-a-website-and-return-urls-only) contains various solutions, [this is the Google search I used](https://www.google.com/search?q=extract+urls+(curl+OR+wget)).

Comment: Basically, you'll want to loop over important URL's within your domain to find/store which pages are 'leaking'.

Comment: The site is several petabytes large with billions of ᴜʀʟs. Near all page aren’t static. Do you have a better solution than crawling it myself ?

Comment: Sounds like you *may* need to run your crawls in a high-concurrency environment. A clustered actor pattern, such as Scala/Java's [Akka](http://akka.io) should do it or a have a look at a similarly-clustered map-reduce pattern (feeding out the URL collection/identification work to sub-units, on [Spark](http://spark.apache.org) or [Hadoop](https://hadoop.apache.org)). I'm including [some related resource URL in a pastebin](http://pastebin.com/hYfpefv0). It would be interesting to find out which direction you go in, please let us know.

Comment: Ok, in fact I have to nothing to with the company, but they aren’t replying to my e‑mail that I sent to their address dedicated for reporting security problems (I was very tired and wrote mistakes, I am afraid I fed them up). But this should be discussed privately.

Comment: any source where i can put like source site (to be scanned) + target site link in it code ?

Answer (score 14):

You can try [PublicWWW](https://publicwww.com/) for search in source/mark-up. It allows to find any HTML, JavaScript, CSS and plain text in web page source code on 167+ million websites.

With PublicWWW you can:

- Find related websites through the unique HTML codes they share, i.e.
  widgets & publisher IDs.
- Identify sites using certain images or badges.
- Find out who else is using your theme.
- Identify sites mentioning you.
- Find your competitor's affiliates.
- Identify sites where your competitors personally collaborate or interact.
- References to use a library or a platform.
- Find code examples on the net.
- Figure out who is using what JS widgets on their sites.
- ...

Of course you can find not only your websites which use some code/mark-up snippet.

Comment: Worth noting that only the websites in the top 1 million are revealed for free. Results from the top 3 million are revealed after registering. The rest are paid. Also, the revealed results only show the domain and not the full URL.

Comment: is this page broken? I don't care if I have to pay to get the information, however when trying to purchase I get "Plan not available" on all items, does somebody know what happened to the page? it has been about 4 months like that