# How do I use the Python Scrapy module to list all the URLs from my website?

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I want to use the Python [Scrapy module](http://scrapy.org/) to scrape all the URLs from my website and write the list to a file. I looked in the examples but didn't see any simple example to do this.

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a site to ask people to write your code for you - *try something* and then come ask a question about a specific problem you run into.

Comment: Have you tried the tutorial there? It's quite self explanatory. If you /have/ tried the tutorial and still have trouble, try posting some code that you've tried first (+1 @Amber)

Comment: Amber, and inspectorG4dget, I wrote the program that does this, but can't post it yet because I don't have enough reputation - there's a waiting time. I'll post the solution tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Here's the python program that worked for me:

```
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.http import Request

DOMAIN = 'example.com'
URL = 'http://%s' % DOMAIN

class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = DOMAIN
    allowed_domains = [DOMAIN]
    start_urls = [
        URL
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        for url in hxs.select('//a/@href').extract():
            if not ( url.startswith('http://') or url.startswith('https://') ):
                url= URL + url 
            print url
            yield Request(url, callback=self.parse)
```

Save this in a file called `spider.py`.

You can then use a shell pipeline to post process this text:

```
bash$ scrapy runspider spider.py > urls.out
bash$ cat urls.out| grep 'example.com' |sort |uniq |grep -v '#' |grep -v 'mailto' > example.urls
```

This gives me a list of all the unique urls in my site.

Comment: That's cool. You have got the answer. Now go ahead and accept the answer... and, oh yeah, there might be a "Self Learner" badge waiting for you. :)

Comment: There's a small bug in this program. The line `if not url.startswith('http://'):` won't handle https links correctly.

Comment: @JoshuaSnider I updated it. But this is a short snippet of sample code, so it's not meant to be authoritative for all situations.

Answer (score 15):

something cleaner (and maybe more useful) would be using [LinkExtractor](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html#link-extractors)

```
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

    def parse(self, response):
        le = LinkExtractor() # empty for getting everything, check different options on documentation
        for link in le.extract_links(response):
            yield Request(link.url, callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: Does this return links inside the website or external also?