# How to find and extract link from webpage?

Tags: python

I have website , e.g `http://site.com`

I would like fetch main page and extract only links that match the regular expression, e.g `.*somepage.*`

The format of links in html code can be:

```
<a href="http://site.com/my-somepage">url</a> 
<a href="/my-somepage.html">url</a> 
<a href="my-somepage.htm">url</a>
```

I need the output format:

```
http://site.com/my-somepage
http://site.com/my-somepage.html
http://site.com/my-somepage.htm
```

Output url must contain domain name always.

What is the fast python solution for this?

Comment: What did you try that didn't work? StackOverflow is not a code writing service, but we will help you if you show some effort in solving the problem first.

Comment: Take a look at an HTML parsing module, such as BeautifulSoup. (Would post a link but I'm on my phone, sorry)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`lxml.html`](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#working-with-links):

```
from lxml import html

url = "http://site.com"
doc = html.parse(url).getroot() # download & parse webpage
doc.make_links_absolute(url)
for element, attribute, link, _ in doc.iterlinks():
    if (attribute == 'href' and element.tag == 'a' and
        'somepage' in link): # or e.g., re.search('somepage', link)
        print(link)
```

Or the same using [`beautifulsoup4`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
import re
try:
    from urllib2 import urlopen
    from urlparse import urljoin
except ImportError: # Python 3
    from urllib.parse import urljoin
    from urllib.request import urlopen

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer # pip install beautifulsoup4

url = "http://site.com"
only_links = SoupStrainer('a', href=re.compile('somepage'))
soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url), parse_only=only_links)
urls = [urljoin(url, a['href']) for a in soup(only_links)]
print("\n".join(urls))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an HTML Parsing module, like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).
Some code(only some):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = '''<a href="http://site.com/my-somepage">url</a> 
<a href="/my-somepage.html">url</a> 
<a href="my-somepage.htm">url</a>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
links = soup.find_all('a',{'href':re.compile('.*somepage.*')})
for link in links:
    print link['href']
```

Output:

```
http://site.com/my-somepage
/my-somepage.html
my-somepage.htm
```

You should be able to get the format you want from this much data...

Answer (score 1):

[Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) is the simplest way to do what you want. There is actually link extracting mechanism [built-in](https://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html?highlight=link%20extractor#link-extractors).

Let me know if you need help with writing the spider to crawl links.

Please, also see:

- [How do I use the Python Scrapy module to list all the URLs from my website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561020/how-do-i-use-the-python-scrapy-module-to-list-all-the-urls-from-my-website)
- [Scrapy tutorial](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html)