# How to list the urls in my website that has a keyword in the page using scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I Tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561020/how-do-i-use-the-python-scrapy-module-to-list-all-the-urls-from-my-website) it lists all the urls in my website.

```html
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.http import Request

DOMAIN = 'example.com'
URL = 'http://%s' % DOMAIN

class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = DOMAIN
    allowed_domains = [DOMAIN]
    start_urls = [
        URL
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        for url in hxs.select('//a/@href').extract():
            if not ( url.startswith('http://') or url.startswith('https://') ):
                url= URL + url 
            print url
            yield Request(url, callback=self.parse)
```

I want to list the urls's that has some text, say "Scrappy Test" in the webpage. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: thanks for providing the link, can you include the code snippet you used, the outcome you expected, what actually resulted from the snippet and and any error stack produced?

Comment: The snippet resulted in the list of url's.

Comment: @RoshanChhetri Did you ever solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have all the urls (as you say in your comment) but want to filter them by a sub-string then try:

```
if 'Scrapy Test' in url:
    print url
    yield Request(url)
```