# What's a better way to limit URLs crawled for each starting URL in scrapy?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, scrapy, web-crawler

I have a list of about 250 website URLs from which I need all URLs to all webpages on that site. One problem is that some websites are so large that my program keeps crawling infinitely. I'm trying to set a limit on that through the following code but it isn't working:

```
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.exceptions import IgnoreRequest
from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy import Spider

class MySpider(Spider):
    name = "spider"
    
    allowed_domains = [
        MY_250_DOMAINS_GO_HERE
    ]

    start_urls = []

    for domain in allowed_domains:
        start_urls.append('http://%s' % domain)

    output_file = open("iterable_links.txt","w+")

    LIMIT = 10
    count = 0

    def parse(self, response):

        if self.count >= self.LIMIT:
            raise IgnoreRequest()
            #raise CloseSpider(f"Scraped {self.LIMIT} items. Eject!")
        self.count += 1

        le = LinkExtractor()
        
        domain = response.url.replace("http://","").replace("https://","").split("/")[0]
        links = le.extract_links(response)
        links = [k for k in links if domain in k.url]

        output_file = open("iterable_links.txt","a+")
        
        for link in links:
            output_file.write("'" + link.url + "',\n")
            yield Request(link.url, callback=self.parse)

"""
REFERENCE:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561020/how-do-i-use-the-python-scrapy-module-to-list-all-the-urls-from-my-website
"""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 'DEPTH_LIMIT' (the default is 0 which is infinity)

```
class MySpider(Spider):
    name = "spider"
    
    allowed_domains = [
        MY_250_DOMAINS_GO_HERE
    ]
    custom_settings = {
        'DEPTH_LIMIT' : 3, 
    }
.................
.................
.................
```