# wget grep sed to extract links and save them to a file

Tags: bash, sed, grep, pipe, wget

I need to download all page links from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meme and save them to a file all with one command.

First time using the commmand line so I'm unsure of the exact commands, flags, etc to use. I only have a general idea of what to do and had to search around for what href means.

```
wget http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meme -O links.txt | grep 'href=".*"' | sed -e 's/^.*href=".*".*$/\1/'
```

The output of the links in the file does not need to be in any specific format.

Comment: Consider just using `links -dump` or `lynx -dump`.

Comment: @cajole0110 You can't (usually) pipe the text if you save it to file instead. That's why either of BMW's commands work but not yours.

Comment: +1 for doing good research before-hand.

Answer (score 4):

Using gnu grep:

```
grep -Po '(?<=href=")[^"]*' links.txt
```

or with wget

```
wget http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meme -q -O - |grep -Po '(?<=href=")[^"]*'
```

Comment: You may also want to add the `-q` flag, to prevent printing the progress bar interleaved with the actual output (the progress bar is printed to stderr, so it doesn't interfere as such, it just looks funky).

Answer (score 1):

You could use `wget`'s spider mode. See this SO answer for an example.

[wget spider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804467/spider-a-website-and-return-urls-only?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Answer (score 0):

```
wget http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meme -O links.txt | sed -n 's/.*href="\([^"]*\)".*/\1/p'
```

but this only take 1 href per line, if there is more than 1, other are lost (same as your original line). You also forget to have a group (`\(` -> `\)`) in your orginal sed first pattern so `\1` refere to nothing