# Copy multiple links from a website

Tags: javascript, url, web

I want to create an app that randomly access pages from another site.
This site has more than 40,000 pages and does not have an api.

How can I collect the url of all these 40,000 pages? Copy and paste will be eternal.

All of these pages follow the same structure, similar to site.com/directory/1.html, site.com/directory/2.html, etc

Comment: Already been answered - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804467/spider-a-website-and-return-urls-only

Comment: @PressingOnAlways That seems directed specifically towards `wget`. OP has tagged this with JavaScript.

Comment: The OP contemplated copying and pasting all the urls suggesting that he can post-process the data. I suggest using wget or some established methodology of grabbing the urls and importing that into your application. I do not see the need to re-invent a web scraping bot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org) is great for this.
Or you could learn [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/) and setup a 'scraper' that will basically grab each page's html via a GET request and parse it using something like [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) (jquery for serverside).

Your question is pretty broad as there are many ways to sink a ship. You just gotta pick a tool and go at it. Goodluck!

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple tools to use for this in different environments. You could achieve this with:

- [Node.js](https://nodejs.org) - The environment
- [request](https://github.com/caolan/async) - The http request tool
- [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) - The html parsing tool which supports jQuery-like selectors like `$("a.somelink-selector")`
- Perhaps the [async library](https://github.com/caolan/async) to more easily control how many requests you'll do at a time