# Getting a list of uls with wget using regex

Tags: bash, shell, wget

I'm starting with page:

```
https://mysite/a"
```

I'd like to spider the page getting the full urls of any nested urls below this that begin with the same stem (like https://mysite/a/b ).

I've tried:

```
$ wget -r --spider --accept-regex "https://...*" 'https://.../' 2>test.txt
```

which produces a large amount of output inclusing what appear to be the urls I'm after like:

```
--2018-04-21 15:04:48--  https:/mysite/a/
Reusing existing connection to mysite:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: 'a/index.html.tmp.tmp'
```

How do I just print out a list of the urls?

Edit:

changed it to

```
$ wget -r --spider  'https://mysite/a/' |grep 'https://mysite/a*' 2>test.txt
```

as a test . No output is being saved in test.txt. The file is empty.

Comment: Try grepping the output first,  something like: `wget -r --spider -qO yourURL | grep "https:.*" 2> test.txt `

Comment: @Sergio please see edit.

Comment: Your regex `https://mysite/a*` will match URLs like `https://mysite/` or `https://mysite/aaaaa`, etc. Perhaps a real-world example will be more helpful. You can try testing a regex with your actual page content at https://regex101.com/ if you like. I'd suggest you try something fairly generic like `grep -o 'https?://[^" ]+'`.

Comment: How do you send the output to the file>? 2>test.txt doesn't produce anything in the file.

Comment: from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804467/spider-a-website-and-return-urls-only : wget -q http://example.com -O - | \
    tr "\t\r\n'" '   "' | \
    grep -i -o '<a[^>]\+href[ ]*=[ \t]*"\(ht\|f\)tps\?:[^"]\+"' | \
    sed -e 's/^.*"\([^"]\+\)".*$/\1/g'