# AHK UrlDownloadToFile - many files, unknown names

Tags: automation, autohotkey

I must download many scanned images (.jpg) from the URL address using autohotkey.

```
UrlDownloadToFile [http://192.168.1.2:1234/storage/emulated/0/TurboScan/Jpeg/*.jpg][1] D:\SCAN\\\*.jpg
```

Unfortunately not working :( Should I use loop or something?

When I'm trying save one image with a specific name - everything is OK.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, really. How should AHK know what to search for? there are infinite possibilities in names.. visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857653/get-a-list-of-urls-from-a-site for futher research

Comment: From what I see here, you are trying to download files from an android device. You are going to need to download a directory listing of the files on your device, then loop through it.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it's possible. I get the similar script on AHK forum (for music clips). Now I have to adjust this to my case. I hope I am able to do this... :D

```
http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/50123-extract-all-urls-from-page-source/?hl=%2Burldownloadtofile#entry698707
```